# Add Google Adsense to an email

Tags: adsense

Is [this answer in google's support](http://support.google.com/affiliatenetwork/publisher/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163188) enouh to say that is ok to put ads in email's I send to my customers?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask Google, not us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it means you can place Google Affiliate Network ads in emails if you comply with the email marketing [program policies](http://www.google.com/ads/affiliatenetwork/publisher/program-policies.html).

You can do this using Feedburner and AdSense for feeds. Then use a mail program like [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) to pick up and send the feeds.

Comment: do you know how to implement Adsense ads inside email? From what I know you can't pu JS in email.

Comment: As I said, you can use Feedburner and AdSense for feeds if it is an RSS passed campaign. Otherwise, yes, adding the code should work. Just be aware a lot of email client's will block the code by default for security/anti-spam purposes. I believe Apple products won't, but try it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

That answer refers specifically to Google Affiliate Network ads. It has nothing to do with AdSense. The *only* supported method for putting AdSense into emails that is not against the AdSense TOS was through AdSense for Feeds and Feedburner, but this was shut down in November, 2012. Currently, as of December, 2012, normal AdSense publishers **cannot** put AdSense units in emails.